# Css Link not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm editing this theme, http://themelize.me/demos/curri2.2/index.htm

I want to add some url's to images of the client section (which has 4 images on index slider)

When I add code by inspecting element, for example;

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="img/clients/client2.png" alt="Client 2 image" class="img-responsive" draggable="false"></a>
```

like this.

The cursor changes, but the link does not work.

I suppose it can be about z-index, and search for it in this theme style file, /theme-style.min.css

found 4 instances, but whatever I change, it did not work.

How can I solve this?

Note: I tried to add link to div's also, but in the theme structure, It overlaps I think, and the last images disappear one by one.

edit: Here is the img-responsive class code,

```
img-responsive{display:block;height:auto;max-width:100%} It is the default bootstrap setting I think. themelize.me/demos/curri2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: Am not sure what you are trying to say is :)

Comment: can you show your `img-responsive` class

Comment: img-responsive{display:block;height:auto;max-width:100%} here is. It is the default bootstrap setting I think. http://themelize.me/demos/curri2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Please edit your question to add new informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Change your structure like this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="item" style="width: 250px; float: left; display: block;">
<img class="img-responsive" alt="Client 2 image" src="img/clients/client2.png" draggable="false">
</a>
```

This working fine

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Slider is using flexslider javascrip library. download the latest version from  this [link](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). you have many api options you can use there. [Demo](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)

Or just add the followinf line after your slider is initiated

```
    $(window).load(function()
    {
      $('.item a').click(function()
      {
         window.location = $(this).attr('href');
       });    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not CSS problem, but JavaScript. Probably there is some kind of `preventDefault()` on those DIVs. You can try to wrap them with link, or change DIVs into  (leave `class="item"` and add `display: block`.